# Find Hidden Webpage Url Address

Tags: asp.net, url, web, scraper

I am trying to find the full webpage address for a form generated by a website.  The website is https://treasurer.maricopa.gov/Parcel/?Parcel=50427029

Once you get there I want to see the web address for the Redemption Statement.  You click on it and then have to click on another link to get the form showing all the information I want to scrape.

Here is the problem.  The web address says https://treasurer.maricopa.gov/Parcel/RedemptionStatement.aspx

I know this is not the full address and is being hidden by the aspx suffix at the end.  However, I can't find a way to determine the complete web address url.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

That is the 'web address url'. That page is using parameters that are being passed in with a POST when you click on 'see redemption statement' as part of the view state. If you install and run Fiddler you can see the information being sent in with the POST. However, it is not this page that you should be interested in, but the RedemptionStatement.aspx page. From here, it looks like it's a POST with a pretty simple JSON payload.

```
{
  "parcelNumber": "50427029",
  "paymentDate": "4/3/2018"
}
```

Install and run Fiddler / Postman to inspect and formulate the POSTs needed.